Derivative of multivariate Gaussian cdf with respect to elements of Sigma matrix
I have been trying to compute the derivative of multivariate Gaussian cdf with respect to elements of Sigma matrix. Let $\Phi$ ($\phi$) stand for a multivariate Gaussian cdf (pdf) with mean vector $\mathbf{\mu}$ and correlation matrix $P$, with its entries $p_{ij} = 1$ for $i=j$ and $\rho$ otherwise. I am looking to compute $\frac{\partial \Phi}{ \partial \rho}$.
For a bivariate case, the result is known and simple. I have been able to derive it myself, but have also found a paper with the result and by using the implementation in R I have been able to check the correctness of the solution, see below. The result is
$$
\frac{\Phi_2 (x_1,x_2;0,P_2)}{\partial \rho} = \phi(x_1,x_2;0,P_2).
$$
Verification in R:
x = rep(0.1,2); rho0 = 0.1; P = matrix(rho0,2,2); diag(P) = 1

F_2 <- function(rho_1){
  P.1 = matrix(rho_1,2,2); diag(P.1)=1
  mvtnorm::pmvnorm(lower = rep(-Inf,2), upper = x, mean = rep(0,2), 
                   corr = P.1, seed = 1)[1]
}

all.equal(numDeriv::grad(F_2, rho0),
mvtnorm::dmvnorm(x = x, mean = rep(0,2), sigma = P))

[1] TRUE

Now, for dimensions higher than 2, it gets a bit more complicated. First, I tried to compute it myself, and while the partial derivative of pdf is very easy and trivial, I am not sure how to proceed with cdf. I have tried computing the integral for $d=3$ by expanding the equations, then by using vector calculus, but I am stuck. Namely, I computed
$$
\frac{\partial \phi(\mathbf{x}, P)}{\partial \rho} = tr ( -1/2  P^{-1} - P^{-1} xx' P^{-1}  ) A ),
$$
where $A$ is $\partial P / \partial \rho$. But I don't know how to integrate this with respect to $x_1, \ldots, x_d$ now. I then found an existing result in a paper that I tried implementing.   Then I found another result in Tong and Plackett which states that, for for example dimension 3, the partial derivative can be written as
$$
\frac{ \partial \Phi_3 (x_1,x_2,x_3;0,P_3)}{\partial \rho} = \phi_m(x_1,x_2;0,P_2) \Phi_c (x_3; \mu_c, \sigma^2_c), 
$$
where $\phi_m$ is the marginal joint distribution of $(x_1,x_2)$ with mean vector 0 and the correlation matrix $P_2$ with the diagonal elements of 1 and $\rho$ elsewhere, and $\Phi_c$ is the conditional density of $x_3$ given $(x_1,x_2)$, which is in this case a univariate Gaussian cdf with mean $\rho(x_1 + x_2)/(1+\rho)$ and variance $\sigma^2_c = - (2 \rho^2 - \rho - 1)/(\rho+1)$. At least, if I interpreted the paper correctly. However, when I try to implement it, the result is numerically wrong.
x = rep(0.1,3); rho0 = 0.1; P = matrix(rho0,3,3); diag(P) = 1
mu_c = (rho0/(1+rho0))*sum(x[1:2])
sigma2_c = - (2*rho0^2 - rho0 -1)/(rho0+1)

F_3 <- function(rho_1){
  P.1 = matrix(rho_1,3,3); diag(P.1)=1
  mvtnorm::pmvnorm(lower = rep(-Inf,3), upper = x, mean = rep(0,3), 
                   corr = P.1, seed = 1)[1]
}

numDeriv::grad(F_3, rho0)
[1] 0.2535275

mvtnorm::dmvnorm(x = x[1:2], mean = rep(0,2), 
    sigma = P[1:2,1:2])*pnorm(q = x[3], mean = mu_c, 
    sd = sqrt(sigma2_c), lower.tail = TRUE)
[1] 0.0844702

So my question is: did I interpret the formula wrong or is the implementation correct but there is a numerical problem in R (ex. with grad function)? If so, would it have anything to do with the way pmvnorm is computed? I know it uses Genz-Brent algorithm which is based on importance sampling techniques, which gives slightly random results which, when the seed is not set, results in completely random numerical gradient. I've found another post saying we can't use a numerical gradient as the function pmvnorm is stochastic. But then, why does it work for the bivariate case? And also, why does it work in case of the numerical optimization, if I don't specify the gradient function myself?
The whole reason I am trying to compute the partial derivative is to feed it to the function like nlm, optim, etc, to hopefully obtain better estimates.
I would very much appreciate any kind of help on this matter.
F_3_noseed <- function(rho_1){
  P.1 = matrix(rho_1,3,3); diag(P.1)=1
  mvtnorm::pmvnorm(lower = rep(-Inf,3), upper = x, mean = rep(0,3), 
                   corr = P.1)[1]
}

numDeriv::grad(F_3_noseed, rho0)
[1] 16.76862

> numDeriv::grad(F_3_noseed, rho0)
[1] 1.71553

> numDeriv::grad(F_3_noseed, rho0)
[1] -4.708667
```


Please use math typesetting. Your question will be more likely to get an answer.

One approach is to make a linear change of coordinates in which the distribution is standard Normal, whose derivatives are easily calculated, and then apply the Chain Rule.
